# Magento 2.2.1 Show Msrp and Actual price on Category list page?

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I want to show MSRP and actual price on product listing page without pop up.

Comment: Give some detailed information in your question so that one can help you that what exactly you want

Comment: on product listing page MSRP price is showing and actual price is display by click on popup link. I want to make it out from pop-up and show it with MSRP price .

Comment: Hi Pooja, what did you end up doing in your case?